# XCode: How to fill UIPickerView in code directly with content?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextfield, uipickerview

How do I do that? i want to fill it with values like EURO, USD, POUND and so on and paste the value into a textfield when i tap on the corresponding row.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField { 
// Make a new view, or do what you want here
UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] 
                        initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 244, 320, 270)];

[self.view addSubview:picker];


return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement in your delegate method `-(NSString*) pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component` that will return titles `@"EURO"`, `@"USD"`, `@"POUND"`, `@"RUB"` for your rows.

For example,

```
-(NSString*) pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch(component)
    {
        case 0:
            return @"EURO";
        case 1:
            return @"USD";
        case 2:
            return @"POUND";
        case 3:
            return @"RUB";
    }
    return @"";
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure he wants to put the items into separate components.

Comment: So you want the UIPickerView to show when you select a row in a TableView?

Comment: Ok, just set `picker.delegate = self;`.

Comment: After creating `UIPickerView` add this line. My code add to the controller where you are creating that picker

Comment: well i want it like this but this doesnt work here? http://www.buggyprogrammer.co.uk/2010/08/18/open-uipickerview-when-user-enters-textfield/

Answer (score 3):

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
     myTextField.text= [PickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write code  in your delegate method

```
-(NSString*) pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

{
return string;
}

In Array add like this  @"one", @"two", @"three", @"four"

Comment: Why do you want to return array?

Answer (score 0):

As others have already written you have to add the above mentiond delegate method to fill up your PickerView with items from an array. For writing the value into a textfield, you can do this in 2 ways. You can either do write a pickerView didSelectRow: delegate method like this:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

{

myTextField.text= [myArray objectAtIndex:row];

}
```

This will update the textField each time you tap on a row. The other way is that you pull the value of the pickerView on a button press or on some other action. Similar to

```
- (void)someAction:(id)sender
{

    NSInteger row = [myPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    myTextField.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:row];

}
```